# Getting error on Http GET method in Angular when converting object to array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I am trying to fetch a simple post data containing below details from Firebase.
I am getting error in the portion where the JavaScript object is getting converted to array using rxjs map operator. The output that i am expecting is an array containing three key value pairs.

I am getting proper response in `responseData` as JavaScript object, but the part where conversion to array is producing error.

Data as stored in Firebase:

```
posts
    -MgsgDidteNiYoG4auXX
        content: "Test content"
        title: "Test"
```

The below is the method that I have written:

```
  private fetchPosts() {
    this.http.get('https://***/posts.json')
    .pipe(map(responseData => {
      let postsArray = [];
      for (let key in responseData) {
        if (responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          postsArray.push({ ...responseData[key],  id: key})
        }
      }
      return postsArray;
    }))
    .subscribe(posts => {
        console.log(posts);
    });
  }
```

I am expecting as below:

```
id: -MgsgDidteNiYoG4auXX
content: "Test content"
title: "Test"
```

The error that is got is as follows:

```
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:51:32 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Object'.  
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Object'.

51           postsArray.push({ ...responseData[key],  id: key})
```

Comment: @Kordrad                                                                                                                                 
 `{-MgsgDidteNiYoG4auXX: {…}}
-MgsgDidteNiYoG4auXX:
content: "Test content"
title: "Test"
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Object`

Comment: I see other issues in the code. But for the moment, this should solve the error: `pipe(map((responseData: any) => {`

Comment: @MichaelD That did it! I believe i didn't think through enough. Thanks

Comment: I've posted an expanded answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding from my comment, adding type definition would remove the current issue.

```js
pipe(map((responseData: any) => {
```

Ideally this would be a specific type instead of `any`.

---

Second, I believe what you wish to do is to merge the parent key as a value to the child object with it's own key as `id`. For that you could use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) function

Try the following

Working snippet:

```js
const responseData = {
  "-MgsgDidteNiYoG4auXX": {
    content: "Test content",
    title: "Test"
  }
}

let result;
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(responseData)) {
  result = { ...value, id: key };
}
console.log(result);
```

```js
this.http.get('https://***/posts.json').pipe(
  map((responseData: any) => {
    let result: any;
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(responseData)) {
      const result = { ...value, id: key };
    }
    return result;
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you've imported the wrong map probably like me

correct import :

`import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

wrong import :

`import { map } from 'rxjs-compat/operator/map';`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).